# Website monitoring

Tags: shell-script

The goal that I am trying to accomplish is to pull HTML code from a website, write it to a file. Once this is done, I want to loop it to do it again and write it to another file. After the second file is written I want it to compare the two files together to see if anything has changed. Here is what I have so far, and it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hopefully this will do everything at once!"

while true;
do 

wget -q -O - http://website.com > websitebaseline.txt

if -e websitebaseline.txt
then
    wget -q -O - http://www.website.com > websitechange.txt
    echo "Update to websitechange.txt has been made"

    if !-e websitebaseline.txt
    then
        wget -q -O - http://www.website.com > webbaseline.txt
        echo "Baseline has been created"

if -e websitebaseline.txt websitechange.txt
then diff -y websitebaseline.txt websitechange.txt --supress-common-lines > Changeinsite.txt
    if !-e websitebaseline.txt
    then 
        wget -q -O - http://www.website.com > websitebaseline.txt   echo "Baseline has been created"
    elif !-e websitechange.txt
    then
        wget -q- O - http://websitename.com > websitenamechange.txt
        echo "Update has been made"

sleep 100;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Way overcomplicating things.

```
#!/bin/bash
left=$(mktemp)
right=$(mktemp)
url="http://url.example.com/"
trap 'rm -f "$left" "$right"' EXIT
for file in "$left" "$right"; do
    wget -q -O "$file" "$url"
done
if diff "$left" "$right" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Changes detected in successive retrievals of '$url'."
fi
```

A similar regime could be used to incrementally note changes over time:

```
left=$(mktemp)
right=$(mktemp)
url="http://url.example.com/"
trap 'rm -f "$left" "$right"' EXIT
# Establish the "baseline":
wget -q -O "$left" "$url"

# Okay, now check for updates forever:
while sleep 30; do
    wget -q -O "$right" "$url"
    if diff "$left" "$right" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "$(date) - Changes detected in '$url'."
        cp "$right" "$left"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Can this be used to create a baseline and detect if changes happen over a long period of time?

Comment: It'd be a simple enough change, either to do it incrementally (i. e. detect every change over time) or statically (i. e. detect every instance that differs from a baseline that would be maintained separately).

Comment: What would it look like for the static detection? I am very new at this and this is really only my second script. And is there a way to write the changes to a file for documentation?

Comment: See the new example added to the answer above.

Comment: Consider `cmp -s` rather than `diff...`

Comment: Why would I want to do a binary compare on files that are presumably going to be plaintext?

Comment: Because you don't  use the output of `diff` except its status code, so `cmp` is more efficient and faster.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to detect a difference between two files, no matter how small the change may be, is to compare their checksums.  To demonstrate here I just used the "md5sum" command to generate the md5 hash of each request.

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q website.com -O site.txt
baseline=$(md5sum site.txt)
echo first request checksum: $baseline
rm site.txt

wget -q website.com -O site.txt
change=$(md5sum site.txt)
echo second request checksum: $change
rm site.txt
```

The output of this script will be the md5 hash from each request, and you'll very easily be able to see if the hashes are the same or different.